# How do you uninstall kerberos from Bash? or Change server name?

Tags: linux, bash, kerberos

I setup the wrong server name and admin name. I sthere a way to change it? instead of uninstalling it? Thanks

Comment: Linux tends to put config files in a hidden directory under your home folder, possibly in `~/.config/kerberos/` or `~/.config/krb5/`

Comment: If you can't `find` or m`locate` those configs, then `apt search kerberos | grep installed` and `sudo apt purge reinstall` ... any packages you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Debian or Ubuntu, then `dpkg-reconfigure krb5-config` will pop up the same "initial setup" dialogs as you get when installing the package. (Alternatively, `apt purge` would uninstall the package *and* remove all of its configuration.)

But in pretty much all systems, you can just edit the file `/etc/krb5.conf` and set your realm name and KDC & kadmin server addresses in there. For example:

```
[libdefaults]
    default_realm = EXAMPLE.COM

[realms]
    EXAMPLE.COM = {
        kdc = kerberos.example.com
    }
```

This is the same for both MIT Krb5 and Heimdal Kerberos.

(Though on a properly set-up realm, the KDCs can be discovered through DNS and don't need to be manually configured in each client's krb5.conf.)

---

If you were trying to set up a new MIT Kerberos KDC server, its database is defined in `/var/lib/krb5kdc/kdc.conf` (this might sometimes be placed in `/etc/krb5kdc` instead). Edit the realm name, delete the files storing the old database, then create a brand new realm using `kdb5_util create -s`.

(Heimdal uses different paths for the KDC configuration, and probably `kadmin --local` to initialize a new realm.)